# what is the tenant level of a office 365 site

Tags: office-365, managed-property

I have a managed property and I have been told that I need to delete it from the tenant level schema. Bit confused to what this means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenant level is your entire Office 365 "world"

That is the level above all your site collections.

To access the Tenant level managed properties go through:

1. In the app launcher click "Admin" this will bring you to 
   https://portal.office.com/admin/default.aspx
2. In the left menu click "Admin | SharePoint" this will bring you to https://XXX-admin.sharepoint.com
3. In the left menu click "Search"
4. In the main content click "Manage Schema" this will bring you to https://XXX-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/searchadmin/ta_listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=tenant where you manage your tenant level managed properties

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge, Tenant level at office 365 is your **site collection level** .

So you have to delete your site collection managed property to get your desire output.

Referred links: just for understand the concept of tenant level.

[Tenant level web template](http://zimmergren.net/technical/office-365-dev-tip-retrieve-all-tenant-level-webtemplates-in-your-office-365-tenant-using-csom)

[Information about tenant](http://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/001_GettingStarted/010_ConnectToTenant.htm)